# Raymarching shader not working with RenderTexture as Target

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, shader, hlsl

I took the Raymarching Shader from the [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Texture3D.html) for Texture3D.

If I add it to a material and set the Texture3D in the material it renders correctly.

But if I set the camera.TargetTexture to a RenderTexture, nothing is rendered into the RenderTexture.

Code for the Shader:

```
Shader "Test/basic_VolumeRendering"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Texture3D("Texture3D", 3D) = "white" {}
        _Alpha("Alpha", float) = 0.02
        _StepSize("Step Size", float) = 0.01
    }
        SubShader
        {
            Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" }
            Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha
            LOD 100

            Pass
            {
                CGPROGRAM
                #pragma vertex vert
                #pragma fragment frag

                #include "UnityCG.cginc"

                // Maximum amount of raymarching samples
                #define MAX_STEP_COUNT 128

                // Allowed floating point inaccuracy
                #define EPSILON 0.00001f

                struct appdata
                {
                    float4 vertex : POSITION;
                };

                struct v2f
                {
                    float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                    float3 objectVertex : TEXCOORD0;
                    float3 vectorToSurface : TEXCOORD1;
                };

                sampler3D _Texture3D;
                float4 _MainTex_ST;
                float _Alpha;
                float _StepSize;

                v2f vert(appdata v)
                {
                    v2f o;

                    // Vertex in object space this will be the starting point of raymarching
                    o.objectVertex = v.vertex;

                    // Calculate vector from camera to vertex in world space
                    float3 worldVertex = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex).xyz;
                    o.vectorToSurface = worldVertex - _WorldSpaceCameraPos;

                    o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                    return o;
                }

                float4 BlendUnder(float4 color, float4 newColor)
                {
                    color.rgb += (1.0 - color.a) * newColor.a * newColor.rgb;
                    color.a += (1.0 - color.a) * newColor.a;
                    return color;
                }

                fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
                {
                    // Start raymarching at the front surface of the object
                    float3 rayOrigin = i.objectVertex;

                    // Use vector from camera to object surface to get ray direction
                    float3 rayDirection = mul(unity_WorldToObject, float4(normalize(i.vectorToSurface), 1));

                    float4 color = float4(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    float3 samplePosition = rayOrigin;

                    // Raymarch through object space
                    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEP_COUNT; i++)
                    {
                        // Accumulate color only within unit cube bounds
                        if (max(abs(samplePosition.x), max(abs(samplePosition.y), abs(samplePosition.z))) < 0.5f + EPSILON)
                        {
                            float4 sampledColor = tex3D(_Texture3D, samplePosition + float3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f));
                            sampledColor.a *= _Alpha;
                            color = BlendUnder(color, sampledColor);
                            samplePosition += rayDirection * _StepSize;
                        }
                    }

                    return color;
                }
                ENDCG
            }
        }
}
```

Script for RenderTexture:

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Volume_Renderer_Debug : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Shader volumeShader;
    public Texture3D data;
    private Camera m_camera = null;
    private Camera m_cameraCopy = null;
    private GameObject cameraCopyObj = null;
    private RenderTexture m_volumeTex = null;


    void Awake()
    {
        m_camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        if (cameraCopyObj != null)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(cameraCopyObj);
        }
        cameraCopyObj = new GameObject("cameraCopy");
        cameraCopyObj.hideFlags = HideFlags.DontSave;
        cameraCopyObj.transform.parent = transform;
        cameraCopyObj.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        m_cameraCopy = cameraCopyObj.AddComponent<Camera>();
        m_cameraCopy.CopyFrom(m_camera);
        m_cameraCopy.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.SolidColor;
        m_cameraCopy.enabled = false;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        DestroyImmediate(cameraCopyObj);
    }

    void OnPreRender()
    {
        m_camera.cullingMask = 0;
    }

    void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dst)
    {
        m_volumeTex = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(Screen.width, Screen.height, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32, RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear);
        m_cameraCopy.targetTexture = m_volumeTex;
        m_cameraCopy.backgroundColor = new Color(0.7f, 0.5f, 0.7f, 0.0f);
        m_cameraCopy.clearFlags = CameraClearFlags.Color;
        m_cameraCopy.cullingMask = 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Volume");
        Shader.SetGlobalTexture("_Texture3D", data);
        m_cameraCopy.RenderWithShader(volumeShader, null);
        Graphics.Blit(m_volumeTex, dst);
    }
}
```

Result of using a material:
[image: Result Material]

Result with RenderTexture as target:
[image: Result RenderTexture]

Comment: I need to use the result from the raymarching shader later in another shader and blend them together, so I need to pass the rendering result to another shader as a texture.

Comment: Which result, the result on the box or the box on the screen?

Comment: I need the result of the top screen, but in a RenderTexture where the rendering is triggered in the OnRenderImage() function.

Comment: So the part I don't understand is why applying a shader to a material and just dragging it to an object, give me a different result than `RenderWithShader(volumeShader, null);`.

When I use any other shader the result is the same but using the raymarching shader nothing happens. I created the render texture with `m_volumeTex = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(Screen.width, Screen.height, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32, RenderTextureReadWrite.Linear);`

Comment: I've made a scene for test and I could see a thin object on the screen. I just made 2 small changes from your code. `m_cameraCopy.cullingMask = -1` and `RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(m_volumeTex)`. I've also tried to set a larger value of `_Alpha` on the material to make the object more visible. So your code should work as expect, you may check if the object is on the correct layer.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions, unfortunately nothing changes for me. 
When I use the `color.a =1` I see a black cube, I think maybe it is not pulling information from the Texture3D correctly and the colour returned is always `float4(0,0,0,0)`.

Comment: You don't have set the 3d texture on the material don't you? Then yes it's blank. If you want global texture to work, you need remove the property `_Texture3D("Texture3D", 3D)` from the shader.

Comment: The material im using is just a standart unlit/color material. Then I set the 3d Texture with `Shader.SetGlobalTexture("_Texture3D", data);` and render with `m_cameraCopy.RenderWithShader(volumeShader, null);`